# adding Virtual Disk for performance (decreased latency) in VM Environment

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, vmware, latency

Given a fixed number of disk accessible in a VM Environment, would one expect any performance gains when adding additional Virtual Disk for the Guest OS?

We have an Oracle Database running on Windows in VMWare, we're experiencing some disk latency issues.  Our application vendor suggested adding additional Virtual Disk to split up the Oracle Datafiles\redo logs\indexes onto separate disk...

While I'm not the VM admin, and I don't have a visibility to the number of disk in the VM Environment, is the logic correct in that adding Virtual Disk COULD "spread the load" better among the existing physical disk? (I know it's not exactly that simple... But I haven't forwarded the request to the VM team yet as I'm trying to learn a bit more myself)